# Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@6.2.2

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to update the cordova platform to android 6.2.2, but I get the following error:

```
c:\xampp\htdocs\project>cordova platform update android@6.2.2
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@6.2.2
Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@6.2.2
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Failed to get absolute path to installed module
```

I couldn't figure out what's wrong, any idea?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an error with `android@6.2.x` and later. I had the same issue and using the below step was able to build my apk.

Do the following:

```
cordova platform remove android
```

Then add `6.1.2` specifically

```
cordova platform add android@6.1.2
```

Also found the following as an [temporary workaround](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12767)

```
cordova platform add android --nofetch
```

[**Solution**](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-building-android-package-in-ionic-cloud-ionic-package/89516)

Comment: I got the same error but i try to possible solution that not getting any solution for that

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting everything from the platforms folder and then installing them again. That solved the issue for me. I have also deleted and re-installed node_modules as the name change requires it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this commnand which ultimately installs latest version:

cordova platform add android --nofetch